# how to make table visible using radio button?

Tags: css, html

as i am new in html, css, php so i am facing so many problems in completing a small project.So please don't mind. I've included a screen shot. Problem is that whenever i click radio button 'Yes' then only the input text fields of corresponding table should work. If i select the button 'No' then the text fields should be hidden i.e it will not take any input and i should be able to proceed without filling up the table. Thanks in advance.

[image]

.html

```
<body>
<form action="reg2.php" method="post">
<div id="formWrap">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="label1" style="color:#0000CC; text-align:center; font-size:30px">B.E. Degree Course Registration</div>  
  </div> <!-- end of 0th row -->

<div id="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="labelusn1">USN</div>
        <div class="inputusn">
            <input type="text" id="usn" required="required" class="usndetail" name="usn"/>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of 1st row -->
    <h1 style="color:#FF0000; font-style:italic; margin-left:55px; font-size:18px">Courses Dropped/Withdrawn/Failed in Previous Year:</h1>
    <div class="row>
     <div class="inputradio1" style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="radio" id="radio" required="required" class="detailradio1" name="sex" Value="Yes" />Yes, I have course(s) dropped/withdrawn/failed in previous year<br/>
        <input type="radio" id="sex" required="required" class="detailradio1" name="sex" value="No"/>No, I don't have course(s) dropped/withdrawn/failed in previous year<br/></div>
  </div> <!-- end of  row -->   
    <table width="719" border="1" align="center" style="margin-top:10px">
  <tr bgcolor="#A7A7A7">
    <td width="87"><div align="center" class="style1">    Course Code </div></td>
    <td width="50"><div align="center" class="style2">    Credits</div></td>
   <td width="87"><div align="center" class="style3">    Status(D/W/F)</div></td>
    <td width="467"><div align="center" class="style4">    Remarks</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="text" name="cc1" style="width:85px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c1" style="width:48px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="s1" style="width:85px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="r1" style="width:465px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
```

I left the rest part of the code...if necessary i will post

Comment: You are going to need some Javascript. Have you got some code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is solved, please check:

Simply add these scripts:

```
<!-- Importing jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Applying Custom JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Disabling Text Fields by default
    $("table input[type='text']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    $(".inputradio1 input[name=sex]").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "No") {
            $("table input[type='text']").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        } else if (val == "Yes") {
            $("table input[type='text']").each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Or checkout the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kDG5t/2/

Comment: working for one table only.if i select one button then it works for both that i don't want

Comment: @SakirAlam Those two tables can have IDs?

Answer (score 1):

something like that http://jsfiddle.net/Z8jU3/1/ ?

```
$('.detailradio1').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id')=='sex' && $(this).is(':checked')){
        $('table').hide();
    }else{
        $('table').show();
    }
})
```

Comment: `if (this.id && this.checked)` jQuery methods aren't needed, and are more 'expensive' to use, for this. Or even `$('table').toggle(this.id && this.checked)`

Answer (score 1):

In html part I am just defining the ID's of input box.

HTML:-

```
    <body>
<form action="reg2.php" method="post">
<div id="formWrap">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="label1" style="color:#0000CC; text-align:center; font-size:30px">B.E. Degree Course Registration</div>  
  </div> <!-- end of 0th row -->

<div id="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="labelusn1">USN</div>
        <div class="inputusn">
            <input type="text" id="usn" required="required" class="usndetail" name="usn"/>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of 1st row -->
    <h1 style="color:#FF0000; font-style:italic; margin-left:55px; font-size:18px">Courses Dropped/Withdrawn/Failed in Previous Year:</h1>
    <div class="row>
     <div class="inputradio1" style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="radio" id="radio" required="required" class="detailradio1" name="sex" Value="Yes" />Yes, I have course(s) dropped/withdrawn/failed in previous year<br/>
        <input type="radio" id="sex" required="required" class="detailradio1" name="sex" value="No"/>No, I don't have course(s) dropped/withdrawn/failed in previous year<br/></div>
  </div> <!-- end of  row -->   
    <table width="719" border="1" align="center" style="margin-top:10px">
  <tr bgcolor="#A7A7A7">
    <td width="87"><div align="center" class="style1">    Course Code </div></td>
    <td width="50"><div align="center" class="style2">    Credits</div></td>
   <td width="87"><div align="center" class="style3">    Status(D/W/F)</div></td>
    <td width="467"><div align="center" class="style4">    Remarks</div></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="text" id="course_code"  name="cc1" style="width:85px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="credits" name="c1" style="width:48px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="status" name="s1" style="width:85px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="remarks" name="r1" style="width:465px;outline:none; border:hidden;margin:1px"/></td>
```

and jquery for this is :-

```
$('#radio').click(function()
{  
  $('#course_code').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#credits').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#status').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#remarks').removeAttr("disabled");
});

$('#sex').click(function()
 {
  $('#course_code').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#credits').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#status').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#remarks').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

If you want that all input box to be disabled on initial page load then you have to mention disabled="disabled" in all input box like this:-

rest all is same ....

Comment: I create a .js file as you gave and i call it after div tag of radio...not working

Comment: for the a.js file you have to write one more line.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radio').click(function()
{  
  $('#course_code').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#credits').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#status').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#remarks').removeAttr("disabled");
});

$('#sex').click(function()
 {
  $('#course_code').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#credits').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#status').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#remarks').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
}); and download the jquery1.9.1.js and call on your main page .

Comment: Have I answered your Question?

Comment: Just add more rows and then check..if it creates any problem then you just send me jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS if you just want the whole section hidden.

If you have the radio(s) on the same DOM level as a container element like a div for example:

```css
div.formContainer {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]#yes:checked ~ div.formContainer {
  display: block;
}
```

The HTML would basically have something along the lines of:

```
<input type="radio" name="yesno" id="yes" /><label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="yesno" id="no" /><label for="no">No</label>
<div class="formContainer">
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" value="Hello World!" />
</div>
```

This SHOULD mean that if "yes" is the current choice then the text input field should be visible and if yes is not the current choice then the field will be invisible.